# Wordpress query - if less than 3 posts, randomly pick posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a query, which returns posts with custom field "featured". The code looks

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'koncert', 
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured', // name of custom field
            'value' => '1', 
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ), 
    'meta_key' => 'datum', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
    'order' => ASC
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$countposts = $loop->post_count;
$count = 1;
// START OF THE LOOP
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    /* do something */
    $count++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

The problem is I need the query to always return at least three 'featured' posts, which is not always the case.

So, what would be the easiest way to check the posts count in the query, and if less than three, randomly choose another post(s) from this custom post type (and still have the query sorted by `'meta_key' => 'datum'`?

Thanks for help

Comment: The only way to do this would be to run the query twice - you need to get the results first to know the count, and then run it again to get your "random" post if there are less than 3. You *probably* want to be using something other than a `LIKE` filter though, based on the value of `1`.

Comment: Thanks, the query actually works fine (when the post is "featured", it returns value 1). What I need is ie. when there are two featured posts only, add one random post into the query and sort it by 'meta_key' => 'datum'...

Comment: The `LIKE` filter will work, but it's not as efficient. If there are only 2 featured, you need to get them sorted on `datum`, then get a random one also sorted on `datum`, and then sort the two arrays using `usort` to get your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second option is to use a SQL query to fetch this information instead of the built in WordPress functions. Gets all the posts for 'koncert' type that are published, then joins the post meta table twice and sorts based on the meta values for the different gets, using LIMIT to return only 3 results.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT p.ID, p.post_content, p.post_title, datum.meta_value as datum, featured.meta_value as featured
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} featured 
        ON featured.post_id = p.ID 
        AND featured.meta_key = 'featured'
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} datum 
        ON datum.post_id = p.ID 
        AND datum.meta_key = 'datum'
    WHERE 
        p.post_type = 'koncert' 
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY featured DESC, datum DESC, RAND()
    LIMIT 3
SQL;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, I tried it now, but it seems to return all the posts sorted by date, not first the one that are featured and than the  others randomly... Any idea?

Comment: Try replacing `IF(featured.meta_value='1', 1, 0) as featured` with `featured.meta_value as featured`

Comment: Works like a charm, and is way more cleaner than the Wordpress query, thanks!

Comment: Great! Not sure if I should be happy or sad at my ability to write WordPress SQL queries from scratch :/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do the initial fetch, see how many results you got, and then "randomly" get a number of posts you are short of the total, marge them, then sort them all based on the datum meta value. The loop set is different since it uses `get_posts()` instead of `WP_Query` to make it easier to work with as an array.

*Note that I have not run the code below, it's a proof of concept and untested*

```
// The total posts to display
$total_count = 3;

// The query args
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'koncert', 
    'posts_per_page' => $total_count, 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured', // name of custom field
            'value' => '1', 
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    ), 
    'meta_key' => 'datum', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
    'order' => ASC
);

// Get the posts that are "featured"
$featured = get_posts( $args );

// Figure out if we need to fetch "random" posts to get to the $total_count
$rnd_count = $total_count - count( $featured );

if ( $rnd_count > 0 ) {
    // Make sure we don't get the same posts
    $post__not_in = array();
    for ( $featured as $f ){
        $post__not_in[] = $f->ID;
    }

    // Set up the args for a random post
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'koncert', 
        'posts_per_page' => $rnd_count, 
        'post__not_in' => $post__not_in, 
        'orderby' => 'rand', // http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Random_posts
    );

    // Get the "random" posts now that we remove the meta filter and excluding the ones we already fetched
    $random = get_posts( $args );

    // Merge into a single array
    $featured = array_merge( $featured, $random );

    // Get the datum meta for each post so we can sort on it
    $sort = array();
    $post_by_id = array();
    for ( $featured as $f ){
        $sort[ $f->ID ] = get_post_meta( $f->ID, 'datum', true );
        $post_by_id[ $f->ID ] = $f;
    }
    // Sort and maintain key since it's the post
    asort( $sort, SORT_STRING ); // use SORT_NUMERIC for numbers, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

    $i = 0;
    for ( $sort as $key => $s ){
        $featured[$i++] = $post_by_id[ $key ];
    }
}

// since we used get_posts() and not WP_Query, use the following to create the loop.
for ( $featured as $f ){
    global $post;
    $post = $f;
    setup_postdata( $post );
    // use the_content() etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it doesn't work for me though. I think one needs to replace the for with foreach (else I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)), and after the change I get Illegal offset type for the line 
$sort[ $f ] = get_post_meta( 'datum', $f->ID, true );
Any idea how to fix this? Thanks for help

Comment: Got it working. I changed the line to $sort[$f->ID] = get_post_meta( $f->ID, 'datum', true );

Comment: Sorry, I have `get_post_meta()` backward, *but* you want to use `$f` as the key, not `$f->ID` as otherwise the `array_keys()` call won't return the actual posts. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for reply, when I change it to `$f`, I get `Warning: Illegal offset type`.

Comment: D'oh, you're right... no using objects as keys in PHP. You have to use the ID for sorting, and then a map to set it back.

Comment: I added some code which should make it work, but it's admittedly a little ghetto so I don't know if this is the best way to do it. It would be a lot easier to just write SQL query to do this most likely.

Comment: Tried your code now, get `Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /www/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/api.php on line 87` - seems like something causing issues with ACF, which I use for my custom fields...

Comment: You aren't calling any ACF fields, so I would look at your presentation - anything calling `the_field()` for example, but again I think it might be best to just run a SQL query and then `get_post()` on each ID.

Comment: Well, I got it working with the `$f->ID`. Anyway, would be of great help if you could give me/us an example of the SQL query.

Comment: I just found a mistake in my code, which has been causing the `Catchable fatal error`. Your code works as is. Thanks for help!